# format of bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am getting errors when running this bash script.
I have checked in all manuals, it looks okay to me?

Help appreciated.

```
  #!/bin/sh
  HOME=/var/www
  sleep 20
  echo 'running' > $HOME/script-1-output.txt
  if  (-f $HOME/script-2-output.txt )
    echo 'script-2 has run' >> $HOME/script-1-output.txt
  else
    echo 'script-2 has not run' >> $HOME/script-1-output.txt
  fi
  if  (-f $HOME/script-3-output.txt)
    echo 'script-3 has run' >> $HOME/script-1-output.txt
  else
    echo 'script-3 has not run' >> $HOME/script-1-output.txt
  fi
```

Comment: What errors? Where? EDIT: I believe you need `if [ -f $HOME/script-2-output.txt ]`, same with the other `if` - note the square brackets, and spaces. Still, for next time, remember to include all the relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, if conditions are wrapped between [] not (). There should always be space between condition and square brackets. And you need then in if-then-else-fi syntax.

```
if [ -f file.txt ]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: Actually, the `[` and `]` are special syntax for the `test` command, so `[ -f file.txt ]` is equivalent to `test -f file.txt`.  It is more correct to say that in bash, you don't use any braces at all around the condition of an `if` statement.  `if test -f file.txt; then ...` is equally correct.

Comment: It is more correct to say that in bash you use ``[[ ]]`` around the conditional expressions. ``if [[ -f file.txt ]]; then``